# Hints to find a certain integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I find $\int\sqrt{x}/(x^2+1)\,dx$?

I tried by substitution and by integration by parts but it doesn't seem to work. I only need hints, not answers.

Comment: Substitute $x=t^2$
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \int \frac{t^2}{(t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1)(t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1) } dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now do partial fractions ... good luck $\ddot \smile$

Comment: This comment may or may not be a better answer than the one answer that's been posted so far, depending on the needs of those asking the question, but it seems to me that factoring $t^4+1$ in that way is something that students learning this sort of thing for the first time often don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking
$$u=\sqrt{x}\text{ and }du=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$

Then you get
$$2\int\frac{u^2}{u^4+1} \, du$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: That seems to be alright. Thank you for the help! :)